# Comparing and checking to see if the last 4 characters in two Strings are the same?

Tags: java, substring

Today I sat my Java Exam and I am hoping I have done enough to pass it.

Although my Java experience is growing I know for a fact that one of the questions I attempted was wrong and I am looking for both clarification of this failure and also a solution please.

The question is this:

> Create a method of type boolean that will return true if the final four character substrings of String a and String b are equal.

My attempt was this:

```
public static boolean test(String a, String b){
    //Lets assume that the Strings are equal
    if(a.substring(-4).equals b.substring(-4)){
        return true;
    }
}
```

I know that this is wrong, but in exam conditions your mind tends to go blank.
The exam is a basic exam where we are attempting to become familiar with the Java syntax.
The exam was also paper based, there was no access to any PC's.

So, please forgive any errors in my code as I am still learning.

Comment: Shouldn't that say `a.substring(-4).equals(b.substring(-4))`?

Comment: Yes, I am typing it the way I wrote the answer for the exam. I know that I missed the brackets for .equals.

Comment: `a.substring(-4)` will give you the last four characters in some languages, **but not Java**.

Comment: Thanks @ajb. Yeah I knew it was wrong. I just want to get it right just in case I come across it again.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, this question was worth 10 marks. So, if I got the first bit right (checking the Strings were greater than 4 characters long) I may still gain 5 marks for that bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, `substring` method takes `(int startIndex[, int endIndex])`.

So what your code does?

Checks if the substring of `a`, starting from `-4` to `a.length`, is equal to the substring of `b`, starting from `-4` to `b.length`.

As you know String indexes starts from `0` so `-4` will throw to you an exception which says to you that you are trying to use a negative index as `startIndex`.

Since you need to check the last four chars you can use `a.length()` (which will return to you the length of the given string) as start index, so `substring` will return to you the last four chars of the string.

```
public static boolean test(String a, String b){
    //Lets assume that the Strings are equal
    return a.substring(a.length() - 4).equals(b.substring(b.length() - 4));
}
```

Here you have a problem, what if the length is less than 4? It will still try to access to a negative index.

I will not repeat @Elliott Frisch answer since already gave to you the answer to this problem.

Comment: That is great. Thanks for this. I did write some code for this but cannot recall now if honest.

Comment: Again, the issue with this one is that you need to ensure that your strings are at least 4 characters long, otherwise it breaks (maybe it is expected to break).

Comment: So, in effect, I was slightly close? I just missed out the .length syntax. I know that is still bad but I am on the right track?

Comment: With this if it would do the check only if the length was the same. It's depends on what the problem asked

Comment: if(a.length() < 4 && b.length < 4){ return false;}

Comment: $$ is &&. And anyway you could choose a flexible way and do the -4 only if length >4 else check the entire string

Comment: Yeah I amended. Thanks though. Its been a long day.

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers are not valid indexes for calling substring, I would do it with something like this,

```
public static boolean test(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() > 4) {
        a = a.substring(a.length() - 4);
        if (b.length() > 4) {
            b = b.substring(b.length() - 4);
        }
    }
    return a.equals(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test("aTest", "bTest"));
    System.out.println(test("aTest1", "bTest"));
}
```

Output is

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

In java substring does not understand the "minus" semantic. You will have to do something like:

```
public static boolean test(String a, String b) {
    String endA = a.substring(Math.max(0, a.length() - 4));
    String endB = b.substring(Math.max(0, b.length() - 4));
    return endA.equals(endB);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last 4 of a String in java by saying

```
stringName.substring(stringName.length() - 4);
```

Comment: The only issue with this one is that you need to ensure that your strings are at least 4 characters long, otherwise it breaks (maybe it is expected to break)

Comment: Yeah, you were headed in the right direction. As Claudio said, the -4 means it could be negative if you don't check against that, but it's assumed that if you want the last 4 you have at least 4 to be the last 4 heh.